# How can I calculate Exponential using CORDIC for numbers outside [-1, 1]?

Tags: verilog, hdl, cordic

I am not able to understand the math behind calculating exponential of a number outside the range [-1, 1) (actually I am not sure what is a good range to compute exp using CORDIC, some place I read [-pi/4, pi/4] and in others I have read [-1, 1)) using CORDIC algorithm. Can someone give an example?

I read following statement at http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371599G-01/lvfpga/ht_exponential/:

"x must be in the range [–1, 1). To compute exp(x) when x is outside this range, find an integer q and a real number r, where r is in the range [0, ln(2)), such that x = q × ln(2) + r. You then can compute 2^q × exp(r), which is equivalent to exp(x). Because r is in the valid range of [–1, 1), you can use this function to compute exp(r)."

But it doesn't make much sense to me as to how can I find q and r?

Second approach I found was at http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp552-cordic-floating-point-operations.pdf which tells us to use to equations after dividing the number into integer and fraction part:

```
cosh(int + frac) = cosh(int) * cosh(frac) + sinh(int) * sinh(frac)
sinh(int + frac) = cosh(int) * sinh(frac) + cosh(frac) * sinh(int)
```

cosh(int) and sinh(int) are taken from lookup table. But this approach is more computationally intensive so I prefer the previous one.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about electronics.

Answer (score 2):

q and r are trivially extracted from the original number. r is the number that has the same bit pattern as the original but right-shifted such that it falls within (-1, 1), and q is the number of times it has been right-shifted.

```
010110101.11 -> (8, 0.1011010111)
```

Comment: 010110101.11 is equal to 181.75 in decimal and 0.101010111 is equal to 0.71 (approx.) in decimal. I can calculate exp(0.71) in decimal using CORDIC. Therefore from the above equation exp(181.75) should be equal to 2^8 * exp(0.71). But they are nowhere close to each other. What am I missing? I have read this explanation for calculating q and r before but I didn't understand it then and I don't understand it now. Please help.